# PHP creating zip archive

Tags: php, ajax, zip, archive

I am creating a zip archive, but it doesn't work. There is no error logged into Error_log.txt. I am requesting a zip archive over ajax and response from ajax is empty, the `$_SESSION['uid']` code looks like this.

```
$folder = md5($array->id);
        $this->deleteIfExists($folder);

        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $name = "users/".$folder."/".$_SESSION['uid'].".zip";

        if($zip->open("users/".$folder."/".$_SESSION['uid'].".zip", ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) != TRUE){
        echo "Doesn't work :-(";        
        }       

        $zip->addFile("users/".$folder."/client_agree/original_".$array->id.".jpg", "agree.jpg");
        /*
        foreach(json_decode($array->imgs) as $key => $val){
        $zip->addFile("users/".$folder."/client_agree/original_".$val.".jpg", $val.".jpg");     
        }
        */
        $zip->close();

        echo $_SESSION['uid'];
```

Comment: Requesting via a direct link is much better, because the browser then knows how to handle the file type from the headers sent.... if you send as an Ajax request, then you need to handle the response from your js code

Comment: Have you tried enabling error messages? `ini_set("display_errors", 1);`

Comment: When calling $zip->open it could be returning an error code rather than TRUE.  http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php  Have you checked the return value there?